# Placing of pillars

Tags: c++

I am trying to place pillars on a board that alternate between these amount of pillars
(I don't think I explained properly), but for example on row 1 it will have 9 pillars and row 2 it will have 8 pillars.  I wanted to try do it in a nested for loop but not really sure how to go about the code within the blocks.

At the moment I have this:
here are my variables:

```
float PegPosX = -1.0f;
float PegYStartPos;
float PegPosY = 6.0f;
int Pegs = 0;
int PegsInRow = 8;

while(Pegs < NumPegs){
     for (int row = 0; row < PegsInRow; ++row) { 
     int num_cols = (row % 2 == 0) ? 9 : 8;
     PegPosY -= 0.5f;
         for (int col = 0; col < num_cols; ++col){ 
             PegPosX += 1.0f; 
            displayPegs[Pegs].PegPosition(PegPosX, PegPosY);
         }
    }
    ++Pegs;
}
```

Comment: yes, you did not explain properly

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int row = 0; row < num_rows; ++row) {
   int num_cols = (row % 2 == 0) ? 9 : 8;
   for (int col = 0; col < num_cols; ++col) {
       placePillar(...);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pete I have tried to adapt your code to mine but still can't see the pillars on my screen.  I think I may have adapted wrong, if you have time I have edited my post and included some code.  Thank you :)

Comment: the Pegs variable isn't being changed in the inner loops, so the pegs will always be positioned at the same place.  Why did you add the outer while loop?

Comment: I added the outer while loop because I have 68 pillars that I need to put down NumPegs is a const which is = to 68.  How would you go about this problem I have delving on this for quite some time.